# MySQL recursive update based on values in the same table

Tags: mysql, recursion, tree

I am having trouble implementing the following structure in MySQL.

Table1:

```
ID  |  Val
1   |  10
2   |  20
```

Table2:

```
ID  |  LeftTableType | LeftID | LeftVal | RightTableType | RightID | RightVal | Operation | Result
1   |      Table1    |    1   |   (10)  |     Table1     |    2    |   (20)   |     +     | (30)
2   |      Table2    |    1   |   (30)  |     Table1     |    2    |   (20)   |     +     | (50)
```

I tried to use a trigger system where an update to Table1 would update the values of Table2. Unfortunately, I needed to then update subsequent values of Table2, which caused a recursive trigger system that MySQL did not like.

I have also been looking into nested sets and tree structures. It seems like they might be what I am looking for, or at least very close.

Is there something obvious that I am missing to implement something like this? This seems like it might lead me to a messy mixture of cursors, recursion, triggers, procedures, and tree structures.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What kind of updates you need? If you want to use mysql trigger system for recursive updates you will fail. But you can use stored procedured for nested updates.

Comment: Stored procedures are what my current solution uses, but since it is using a cursor, it relies a Table2ID to be less than the key: ID. I also had to use a few SELECT ... AS statements to get MySQL to stop complaining.  Ideally it would update all tables and handle any circular reference gracefully.